# Error while connecting to SQL Server from pyspark

Tags: python, sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

```py
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext

from impala.dbapi import connect
import sys

sc = SparkContext("local", "first app")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
    config = yaml.safe_load(file)
print(config)

table_name = 'loadout'

df = sqlContext.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", config['db_config']['url']) \
    .option("dbtable", "(SELECT TOP 100 * FROM dbo.{0})".format(table_name)) \
    .option("user", config['db_config']['username']) \
    .option("password", config['db_config']['password']) \
    .option("driver", config['db_config']['driver']) \
    .load()

df.show()
```

It is throwing error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/rkumbar/ddl_generation/test.py", line 34, in <module>
>     .option("driver", config['db_config']['driver']) \   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.12.1-1.cdh5.12.1.p0.3/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 139, in load   File
> "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.12.1-1.cdh5.12.1.p0.3/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__   File
> "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.12.1-1.cdh5.12.1.p0.3/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
> line 45, in deco   File
> "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.12.1-1.cdh5.12.1.p0.3/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
> line 308, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
> occurred while calling o56.load. :
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near
> the keyword 'WHERE'.
```

My spark submit command:

```
spark-submit --driver-class-path /home/xyz/ddl_generation/mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar test.py config.yml
```

Comment: What if you put your options as kwargs in the `options()` function like `df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url=config['db_config']['url'], dbtable=..., user=...).load()`? Does it give the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when i change that 'dbtable' query in other variable and passing into that option.

```
mssqlquery = """ (
        SELECT TOP 100 *
        FROM dbo.xyz
        ) t """

...
dbtable= mssqlquery,
...
```